# What is the best way to account for integer overflow in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I have a `double` value that will be passed to `Round`, and I need to make sure it won't overflow an `Int64`. If it would overflow, I just set the value to 0. What is the best way of doing this? I thought about two ways:

1. Handle the exception

```
try
  rounded := Round(value);
except
on E: EInvalidOp do
  rounded := 0;
end;
```

2. Compare against `Int64.MaxValue` and `Int64.MinValue`

```
if (CompareValue(value, Int64.MaxValue) <> GreaterThanValue) and (CompareValue(value, Int64.MinValue) <> LessThanValue) then
  rounded := Round(value)
else
  rounded := 0;
```

I'm wondering what is the best approach to handle this problem. Performance is a concern for me. I'm using Delphi 10.3.

Comment: In case you need numbers bigger than int64 you can try https://github.com/rvelthuis/DelphiBigNumbers

Comment: What about using UInt64?

Comment: i mean, if you need big numbers above zero and overflowing occurs only sometimes, then in UInt64 with it's "double capacity" it would probably happen very rarely if any at all, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your main concern is performance, which is the best is "It depends".

If you expect `value` to overflow an Int64 often,  the 2nd one is better, otherwise, the first one would be better.

The first one will be slightly faster every time it doesn't raise an exception and much slower everytime it does.

For most use cases, I'd say #1 would be faster.

Comment: In this case it's more of a failsafe, so I guess I will go for the first one. Thanks!